# Aqua Data Studio alternative

Tags: mysql-workbench, aquafold, aqua-data-studio

I am using Aqua Data Studio for my internship project. But the evaluation period has finished and now I cannot use it anymore. Please can you suggest me an IDE that is similar to Aqua Data Studio? Some software that is not commercial.

I would like to register some Oracle databases servers and PostreSQL.

Can I use MySQL Workbench? Would that be possible with it? Is there any difference?

Comment: You cannot use MySQL Workbench, as it only can work with MySQL databases (as the name implies), except for doing a migration from a 3rd party RDBMS to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the technical information available in the Aqua Data Studio menu Help -> Support Information and email the above information to the support email address, architect@aquafold.com and support might extend your evaluation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use google data studio, which is free.